# How to create TreeSet using an existing HashSet with data in it?

Tags: java, collections, comparator, hashset, comparable

I am trying to create TreeSet using an existing HashSet with data in it.
But I could not find an overloaded method where I can pass an external Comparator?

Is there way I can use external comparator while creation of TreeSet?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Bus> m = new HashSet<>();
        Bus b1 = new Bus(1, "bhl", "udr");
        Bus b2 = new Bus(2, "ahmd", "mum");         
        m.add(b1);
        m.add(b2);
        //Below will create treeset using default comparable logic.
        Set<Bus> treeObject = new TreeSet<>(m);

        // There is no overloaded constructor like this.
        Set<Bus> treeObject = new TreeSet<>(m, new BusComparator());
```

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps :

```
Set<Bus> treeObject = new TreeSet<>(new BusComparator());
treeObject.addAll(m);
```

Comment: That is after all what the other constructor is doing, if you look at the source code: `public TreeSet(Collection<? extends E> c) { this(); addAll(c); }`